# Creating a function in R that transforms strings into integers, over the entire dataframe

Tags: r, function, loops

I need to create a function in R that transforms all entries of a dataframe, which are character strings, into integers, according to a previouly determined "translation code".

**Sample of input data:**

```
Question 1          Question 2    Question 3

Strongly Agree      Agree         Disagree

Strongly Disagree   Neutral       Don't Know
```

The dataset I'll work with will have over 1000 lines and 50 columns. Each answer needs to be translated into an integer value. The formula for translation is:

> Strongly disagree = 1, Disagree = 2, Neutral = 3, Agree = 4, Strongly agree
>    = 5, Don't know = 0.

**So the function output over this sample data would be**

```
Question 1  Question 2  Question 3

5           4           2

1           3           0
```

**My function attempt:**

```
transform <- function(x)

{
  for (i in x[i, ]

  {
  if (i == 'Discordo fortemente')  {i == 1}
  if (i == 'Discordo')  {i == 2}
  if (i == 'Não concordo nem discordo') {i == 3}
  if (i == 'Concordo')  {i == 4}
  if (i == 'Concordo fortemente')  {i == 5}
  if (i == 'Não sei dizer')  {i == 0}
  }

}
```

The language above is portuguese. Obviously the code doesn't work and I have been banging my head against the wall for nearly 2 hours. Any solution to my problem is welcome, although my idea is to build a function that works for one column, then use it with lapply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not this:

```
library(dplyr)
transform_fct <- function(var) {
  case_when(
    var == "Strongly disagree" ~  1,
    var == "Disagree" ~ 2,
    var == "Neutral" ~ 3,
    var == "Agree" ~ 4,
    var == "Strongly agree" ~ 5,
    var == "Don't know" ~ 0
  )
}
x <- x %>%
  mutate_all(transform_fct)
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using a `case_when` function. For example

```
library(dplyr)
x %>& 
 mutate_all(~case_when(.x == 'Discordo fortemente' ~ 1,
                       .x == 'Discordo' ~ 2, 
                       .x == 'Não concordo nem discordo' ~ 3, 
                       .x == 'Concordo' ~ 4, 
                       .x == 'Concordo fortemente' ~ 5, 
                       .x == 'Não sei dizer' ~ 0))
```

Here, `x` is your data. This code modifies **all** columns. 
If you have other columns which you do not want to transform you can use the `mutate_at` instead of `mutate_all` function.

If you want to make your code work you have to modify as follows:

```
transform <- function(x) {

  y <- seq_along(x)

  for (i in 1:length(x)) {
    if (x[i] == 'Discordo fortemente')  {y[i] = 1}
    if (x[i] == 'Discordo')  {y[i] = 2}
    if (x[i] == 'Não concordo nem discordo') {y[i] = 3}
    if (x[i] == 'Concordo')  {y[i] = 4}
    if (x[i] == 'Concordo fortemente')  {y[i] = 5}
    if (x[i] == 'Não sei dizer')  {y[i]= 0}
}

  return(y)
}

transform(c("Discordo", 'Concordo fortemente', 'Não sei dizer'))
[1] 2 5 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Although I have to say that with your correction of my code, I get the following error:

```Error in lapply(.x, .f, ...) : object 'i' not found```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I already got a solution. Although I have to inform you that your fix for my code doesn't work. I get this output:

```[1]  5  5  5  5  5  5  4  4  9 10  5 12  4  2 15  4 17  4  1  2 21  5  5  4 25  2  1  1 29  5 31  5  4  2  1  5  5 38  2  1  5  4 43  2  1  2  4  5 49  5  4
[52] 52  2  5 55  4  2  1  2 60  4  5 63  5  4 66  1  2 69  4  5 72
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)```

Comment: can you type `warnigs()` in your console and post the output. For me the code works. I included a little example at the end.
If your question is answered please consider accepting one of the answers.

Comment: ```1: In if (notas2[i] == "Discordo fortemente") { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (notas2[i] == "Discordo") { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In if (notas2[i] == "Não concordo nem discordo") { ... :```

And this goes on for 50 messages.

Comment: I did accept the answer that solved it. By the way if you want to, I can send you a sample of my data through email. It's in Excel and it's the sample dataset that I'm actually working with.

Comment: The above function only works if the input `x` is a vector, not if it is a data.frame

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i in colnames(x)) {
  x[,i] <- sapply(x[,i], function(j) switch(j,
                   "Discordo fortemente" = 1,
                   "Discordo" = 2,
                   "Não concordo nem discordo" = 3,
                   "Concordo" = 4,
                   "Concordo fortemente" = 5,
                   0))
}
```

This approach uses base R if you don't want to learn `dplyr`, but can get unweildly in general.

Answer (score 1):

If you had consistent case you could do just :

```
mapping <- c(`Strongly disagree` = 1, Disagree = 2, Neutral = 3, Agree = 4,
  `Strongly agree` = 5, `Don't know` = 0.)

df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) mapping[x])
```

or

```
df[] <- mapping[unlist(df)]
```

Because you don't, you can do:

```
mapping <- setNames(mapping,toupper(names(mapping)))
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) mapping[toupper(x)])
df
#   Question.1 Question.2 Question.3
# 1          5          4          2
# 2          1          3          0
```

or

```
df[] <- mapping[toupper(unlist(df))] # (same output)
```

**data**

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,text="
'Question 1'          'Question 2'    'Question 3'
'Strongly Agree'      Agree         Disagree
'Strongly Disagree'   Neutral       'Don\\'t Know'")
```